# Line 141. parse error, unexpected IDENTIFIER

Tags: vhdl

guys help me solve this please.in my vhdl code it says  Line 141. parse error, unexpected IDENTIFIER on inmplementation check syntax and on simulation behavioral check syntax is says Line 141: Syntax error near "K".
MY code:

```
    -- Company: 
    -- Engineer: 
    -- 
    -- Create Date:    20:01:29 03/22/2016 
    -- Design Name: 
    -- Module Name:    Counter - Behavioral 
    -- Project Name: 
    -- Target Devices: 
    -- Tool versions: 
    -- Description: 
    --
    -- Dependencies: 
    --
    -- Revision: 
    -- Revision 0.01 - File Created
    -- Additional Comments: 
    --
    --------------------------------------------------------------
    library IEEE;
    use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

    -- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
    -- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
     --use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

     -- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
    -- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
    --library UNISIM;
    --use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

    entity Counter is
      Port ( IN0 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           IN1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           IN2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           IN3 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           UDbar : in  STD_LOGIC;
           CLOCK : in  STD_LOGIC;
           LDbar : in  STD_LOGIC;
           RESET : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Q : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           Qbar : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (3 downto 0);
           EN : in  STD_LOGIC);
    end Counter;

    architecture Behavioral of Counter is


    Component DFF is
     Port ( D : in  STD_LOGIC;
        RST : in  STD_LOGIC;
        CLK : in  STD_LOGIC;
        Q : out  STD_LOGIC;
        Qbar : out  STD_LOGIC);
    end component;
    Component MUX4x2 is
     Port ( A : in  STD_LOGIC;
           B : in  STD_LOGIC;
           C : in  STD_LOGIC;
           D : in  STD_LOGIC;
           Sel0 : in  STD_LOGIC;
              Sel1 : in  STD_LOGIC;
              X : out  STD_LOGIC);
     end component;
     signal K,L,M,XS,Qmux,NQmux:std_logic_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);



    begin

    MUX0: MUX4x2 port map
    (A=>Qmux(0),
     B=>NQmux(0),
     C=>IN0,
     D=>IN0,
     Sel0=>M(0),
     Sel1=> NOT (LDbar),
     X=>XS(0));


     MUX1: MUX4x2 port map
     (A=>Qmux(1),
      B=>NQmux(1),
      C=>IN1,
      D=>IN1,
      Sel0=>M(1),
      Sel1=>not (LDbar),
      X=>XS(1));


    MUX2: MUX4x2 port map
    (A=>Qmux(2),
     B=>NQmux(2),
     C=>IN2,
     D=>IN2,
     Sel0=>M(2),
     Sel1=>not LDbar,
     X=>XS(2));


    MUX3: MUX4x2 port map
     (A=>Qmux(3),
      B=>NQmux(3),
      C=>IN3,
      D=>IN3,
      Sel0=>M(3),
      Sel1=>not LDbar,
      X=>XS(3));

    D0: DFF port map
    (D=>XS(0),
     RST=>RESET,
     CLK=>CLOCK,
     Q=>Qmux(0),
     Qbar=>NQmux(0));

     D1: DFF port map
    (D=>XS(1),
     RST=>RESET,
     CLK=>CLOCK,
     Q=>Qmux(1),
     Qbar=>NQmux(1));

     D2: DFF port map
     (D=>XS(2),
      RST=>RESET,
      CLK=>CLOCK,
      Q=>Qmux(2),
      Qbar=>NQmux(2));

      D3: DFF port map
     (D=>XS(3),
      RST=>RESET,
      CLK=>CLOCK,
      Q=>Qmux(3),
      Qbar=>NQmux(3));



      process( K,L,Qmux,RESET,CLOCK,LDbar,UDbar,EN )


      K(0)<=UDbar AND EN;----------------!!!!this line!!!!!---------------------
      L(0)<=(NOT UDbar) AND EN;
      M(0)<=K(0)OR L(0);
      K(1)<=EN AND Qmux(0) AND UDbar;
      L(1)<=EN AND Qmux(0) AND (NOT UDbar);
      M(1)<=K(1) OR L(1);
      K(2)<=EN AND Qmux(0) AND Qmux(1) AND UDbar;
      L(2)<=EN AND Qmux(0)AND Qmux(1) AND (NOT UDbar);
      M(2)<=K(2) OR L(2);
      K(3)<=EN AND Qmux(0) AND Qmux(1) AND Qmux(2) AND UDbar;
      L(3)<=EN AND Qmux(0)AND Qmux(1) AND Qmux(2) AND (NOT UDbar);
      M(3)<=  (K(3) OR L(3));
      IN3 = '0';
      IN2= '0';
      IN1= '1';
      IN0= '1';

     Wait until (CLOCK'Event AND CLOCK = '1'); 

     If RESET='1' AND LDbar='1' AND EN='0' Then 
     Qmux(0)= '0' AND Qmux(1)= '0' AND Qmux(2)= '0' AND Qmux(3)= '0';

     Elsif RESET='1' AND LDbar='0' AND EN='0' Then 
     Qmux(0)= '0' AND Qmux(1)= '0' AND Qmux(2)= '0' AND Qmux(3)= '0';

     Elsif RESET='0' AND LDbar='0' AND EN='0' Then   
     Qmux(0)= '0' AND Qmux(1)= '0' AND Qmux(2)= '1' AND Qmux(3)= '1';

     end if;
     end process;


   end behavioral;
```

Comment: Please remove all the code which is not related to the syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a `begin` statement after the line `process(K,L, ...)`.

It is quite common to have to look at the lines *before* the line that showed the error. The line number in the error message isn't always the line that you made a mistake on.

Answer (score 1):

I teach VHDL. Missing the `begin` seems to be a common mistake. Many constructs in VHDL have similar three line structure

```
<something>
  -- declare stuff here
begin
  -- do stuff here
end <something>;
```

eg:

```
process
  -- declare stuff here (eg constant, variable, procedure declarations)
begin
  -- sequential code here
end process;
```

and

```
architecture
  -- declare stuff here (eg constant, variable declarations)
begin
  -- concurrent code here
end architecture;
```

and

```
function
  -- declare stuff here (eg constant, variable declarations)
begin
  -- sequential code here
end function;
```

and

```
procedure
  -- declare stuff here
begin
  -- sequential code here
end procedure;
```

Comment: You listed `function` twice identically.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Matthew Taylor nor scary_jeff left you with a working design there are more syntax errors

In addition to their `begin` I made some changes to the process:

```
    process ( k, l, qmux, nqmux, udbar, en) -- reset, clock, ldbar, udbar, en )
    begin  -- added per scary_jeff, matthew taylor

        -- k(0) <= udbar and en;  ---!!!!this line!!!!!-----
        -- l(0) <= not udbar and en;
        -- m(0) <= k(0) or l(0);
        -- m(0) <= en;               -- inverts qmux(0) for up or down

        k(1) <= en and qmux(0)  and     udbar;
        l(1) <= en and nqmux(0) and not udbar;  -- nqmux not qmux
        m(1) <= k(1) or l(1);

        -- m(1) <= en and  (
        --                  ( qmux(0)  and     udbar) or
        --                  ( nqmux(0) and not udbar)
        --                 );

        k(2) <= en and qmux(0)  and qmux(1)  and     udbar;
        l(2) <= en and nqmux(0) and nqmux(1) and not udbar; -- nqmux not qmux
        m(2) <= k(2) or l(2);

        k(3) <= en and qmux(0)  and qmux(1)  and qmux(2)  and     udbar;
        l(3) <= en and nqmux(0) and nqmux(1) and nqmux(2) and not udbar; -- nqmux
        m(3) <=  k(3) or l(3);

        -- in3 = '0';  -- These are input ports and signals ( use "<=" )
        -- in2 = '0';
        -- in1 = '1';
        -- in0 = '1';

    -- wait until clock'event and clock = '1';  -- none of this is used

        -- if reset = '1' and ldbar = '1' and en = '0' then 
        -- qmux(0)= '0' and qmux(1)= '0' and qmux(2)= '0' and qmux(3)= '0';

        -- elsif reset='1' and ldbar='0' and en='0' then
        -- qmux(0)= '0' and qmux(1)= '0' and qmux(2)= '0' and qmux(3)= '0';
        --
        -- elsif reset='0' and ldbar='0' and en = '0' then
        -- qmux(0)= '0' and qmux(1)= '0' and qmux(2)= '1' and qmux(3)= '1';
        --
        -- end if;
    end process;


    q <= qmux;       -- added
    qbar <= nqmux;   -- added

end architecture behavioral;
```

Notably you had both increment and decrement values set for all '1's on counter bits to the right. I assumed udbar meant '1' for up and '0' for down.

You can see I slimmed the sensitivity list down, the commented out if statement and wait statement aren't need and aren't used.

You also can't assign to input ports and shouldn't have multiple drivers on qmux.

A couple of side points.

The two terms for m(0) are the same and you can simplify that to just the enable (en).

You don't need the intermediary terms l an k, I left them in.  Note I reduced the length of l, m and k and hooked up en directly to MUX0:

```
signal k, l, m:         std_Logic_vector (3 downto 1);
signal xs, qmux, nqmux: std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);

mux0:                      -- swap inputs to use ldbar directly
    mux4x2 
        port map ( 
            a => in0,      -- was qmux(0),
            b => in0,      -- was nqmux(0),
            c => qmux(0),  -- was in0,
            d => nqmux(0), -- was in0,
            sel0 => en,    -- was m(0),     -- an optimization
            sel1 => ldbar, -- was not ldbar
            x => xs(0)
        );
mux1: 
    mux4x2 
        port map (
            a => in1,      -- was qmux(1),
            b => in1,      -- was nqmux(1),
            c => qmux(1),  -- was in1,
            d => nqmux(1), -- was in1,
            sel0 => m(1),
            sel1 => ldbar, -- was not ldbar
            x => xs(1)
        );
mux2: 
    mux4x2 
        port map (
            a => in2,      -- was qmux(2),
            b => in2,      -- was nqmux(2),
            c => qmux(2),  -- was in2,
            d => nqmux(2), -- was in2,
            sel0 => m(2),
            sel1 => ldbar, -- was not ldbar
            x => xs(2)
        );
mux3: 
    mux4x2 
        port map (
            a => in3,      -- was qmux(3),
            b => in3,      -- was nqmux(3),
            c => qmux(3),  -- was in3,
            d => nqmux(3), -- was in3,
            sel0 => m(3),
            sel1 => ldbar, -- was not ldbar
            x => xs(3)
        );
```

I also swapped a, b and c,d inputs to the multiplexers to use ldbar as sel1. There's a requirement that an actual be a static expression.

And those changes along with a genned up testbench, mux4x2 and dff that assumes a positive reset gives:

[image: counter_ud_tb.png]

a working updown counter.

So the design was 99 percent there. The errors besides the process begin were not getting the increment and decrement values right for toggling between qmux(n) and nqmux(n), and a bit of dead wood in the process.

Oh, and note the two added concurrent signal assignments assigning qmux to q and nqmux to qbar below the process in the counter.

There'd be a few things I'd do differently, no intermediary signals for terms for m(3 downto 1), in0 - in 1 could be inp(3 downto 0).

The testbench:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity counter_ud_tb is
end entity;

architecture foo of counter_ud_tb is
    signal in0:    std_logic := '1';  -- load value "1111"
    signal in1:    std_logic := '1';
    signal in2:    std_logic := '1';
    signal in3:    std_logic := '1';
    signal udbar:  std_logic;
    signal clock:  std_logic := '0';
    signal ldbar:  std_logic;
    signal reset:  std_logic;
    signal q:      std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal qbar:   std_logic_vector (3 downto 0);
    signal en:     std_logic;

begin
DUT:
    entity work.counter
        port map (
            in0 => in0,
            in1 => in1,
            in2 => in2,
            in3 => in3,
            udbar => udbar,
            clock => clock,
            ldbar => ldbar,
            reset => reset,
            q => q,
            qbar => qbar,
            en => en
        );
CLKGEN:
    process
    begin
        wait for 5 ns;
        clock <= not clock;
        if now > 380 ns then
            wait;
        end if;
    end process;

STIMULI:
    process
    begin
        wait for 6 ns;
        reset <= '1';
        ldbar <= '1';
        en <= '0';
        udbar <= '1';  -- up
        wait for 20 ns;
        reset <= '0';
        ldbar <= '0';
        wait for 10 ns;
        ldbar <= '1';
        wait for 10 ns;
        en <= '1';  
        wait for 160 ns;
        udbar <= '0';  -- down
        wait for 160 ns;
        en <= '0';
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```